# Runing nodeJs npl-with-dispatch BotBuilder sample behind corporate proxy

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I'm trying to run the sample "14.nlp-with-dispatch" on my local machine and test it with the emulator. I have a luis and Qna azure services.
I have modified some code under node_module to add proxy configuration (just to run the exemple on my local machine) : this works for my luis service but I didn't find where to add proxy configuration for qna service knowing that I have tried to use npm packages "global-tunnel" and "global-tunnel-ng" but this didn't work for me because my node version is 12.9.1.
Has anyone experienced this?
Is there any other way to add proxy configuration for this two services ?

Answer (score 0):

Answered you in GitHub, but adding here for reach. This is a [known issue currently being worked on](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/717).